# When does Stashing happen?

Tags: git, git-stash

I modified a file in branch1, it was in "Modified" state and later I checkoud to branch2 without stashing it as I was expecting it to take a Automatic stash.

But Stashing did not happen and the same file was in "Modified" state in the branch2 as well.

Can you please explain me about this?

Comment: best tool I've seen to understand git stages: http://ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html

Comment: I've never heard of "automatic stash". Stashing happens when you use the `git stash` commands, which apparently you didn't.